# Como acessar pastas e copiar os arquivos em Python?

Tags: python

Olá, sou novo em Python.
Eu tenho uma pasta "MAIN". Dentro desta pasta tem diversas outras pastas. Nestas pastas eu tenho o arquivo "IQ.jpg". Gostaria de saber como eu faço para acessar todas as pastas dentro da pasta MAIN e copiar os arquivos "IQ.jpg" para outra pasta "NOVA_PASTA", ao mesmo tempo que ele copia, eu gostaria que ele renomeasse o arquivo para o nome da pasta que ele foi puxado. Por exemplo

> O arquivo "IQ.jpg" está na pasta "Meus_calculos", está pasta está dentro da pasta "MAIN". Quando o arquivo  "IQ.jpg" for copiado para a pasta "NOVA_PASTA", gostaria que o programa renomeasse este arquivos para "IQ-Meus_calculos.jpg"

Basicamente eu gostaria que o programa percorresse todas as pastas, copiasse os arquivos e renomeasse eles de acordo com o nome da pasta da qual foi retirado para não haver duplicação de arquivos na pasta, visto que em todas as pastas tem o arquivo com o mesmo nome e extensão.
Seria possível fazer isto?

**Aqui está o código que eu tentei**

```
from shutil import copy
from pathlib import Path
import os


src = Path(r".\D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\old_folder")
filename = "IQ"
dst = Path(r".\D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\new_folder")
idx = 0

directory_list = list()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\old_folder", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        directory_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))
print(directory_list)

for file in src.iterdir():
    if file.is_file() and file.stem == filename:
        idx += 1
        copy(file, (dst / f"Archive_{idx}").with_suffix(file.suffix))
insira o código aqui
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
```

- Há dois jeitos de mover e renomear, veja:

Nessa parte, o arquivo será renomeado e movido

```
os.rename("diretorio/origem/nome-do-arquivo", "diretorio/destino/novo-nome-arquivo")
```

Usando shutil, você poderá mover o arquivo

```
shutil.move("diretorio/origem/nome-do-arquivo", "diretorio/lugar-para-onde-sera-movida/novo-nome-do-arquivo")
```

Comment: Utilizando esse método que vc falou encima, como eu faria para que o meu programa entrasse em várias pastas e copiasse os arquivos? OBS: tem 1 pasta com diversas pastas dentro.

Comment: Você pode usar a biblioteca glob do python https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html, assim você pode pegar os arquivos recursivamente dentro das pastas, basta você passar o padrão do arquivo, por exemplo: *.txt*

Comment: agradeço a ajuda

Comment: está bem legal a resposta - Eu sugeriria explorar a biblitoca "pathlib" e usar objetos "pathlib.Path" para trabalahr com os nomes, e até com a cópia dos arquivos - o código fica mais conciso e fácil de manter.  Quer dar uma olhada?